# ASP.NET MVC Modelbinder with optional values in F#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC with F#.
I want to post a form with optional values:

```
[<Post>]
member this.Post (form: MyForm) =
    <do stuff>

[<CLIMutable>]
type MyForm = {
    SomeValue: Option<string>
}
```

This doesn't work. `SomeValue` turns up as null, no matter if I send it in or not.

What are my options? (no pun intended)